# Pair of straight lines problem: Prove that $g (a_1+b_1)=g_1 (a+b) $

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

If the lines joining the origin and the point of intersection of the curves $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx=0$ and $a_1x^2+2h_1xy+b_1y^2+2g_1x=0$ are mutually perpendicular then prove that $g (a_1+b_1)=g_1 (a+b) $.

Finding points of intersection seems to tedious.Any better method ?

Comment: You can also do this by considering $y=mx+c$ to be the line throught the intersection of the curves using it and then homogenizing each curve and comparing the equations. It won't be difficult either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

The equation of pair straight lines passing through the intersection of

$$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx=0,a_1x^2+2h_1xy+b_1y^2+2g_1x=0$$

can be written as

$$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+K(a_1x^2+2h_1xy+b_1y^2+2g_1x)=0$$

$$x^2(a+Ka_1)+xy(\cdots)+y^2(\cdots)+x(\dots)=0\  \ \ \  (1)$$

Now the equation of pair straight lines passing through the origin can be written as $$(y-mx)\left(y+\dfrac1mx\right)=0\iff ?=0\  \ \ \ (2)$$

We need $(1),(2)$ to be identical

Comment: Hehe !Great you are :)! Got it :-D Yahoo:)